# Altering Tables using Tablenames from other Table

Tags: postgresql, alter-table, alter-database

I have a database with several tables and i have a table which contains all tablenames which I want to alter.

I want to perform a query like this:

```
ALTER TABLE (SELECT "TABLE_NAME" FROM "RESOURCE_TABLES)  DROP COLUMN ID;
```

My Table RESOURCE_TABLE with Table Names:

```
TABLE_NAME     ID  

Table1          1            
Table2          2
Table3          3
  ...          ...
```

How can I alter all tables named in the table in the column TABLE_NAME with a loop or a query?

So i want Table1,Table2,Table3 to drop a column id without executing a single alter table query on each table because maybe the tables are 100 Tables.

Comment: You don't indicate your DBMS, but you might find [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/112272/stored-procedure-for-adding-cascade/112481#112481) useful

Comment: thanks for the hint i added it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop using an EXECUTE statement.  I believe [this post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/114779/14504) has the exact answer you're looking for, you just need to change the ALTER statement.